# jQuery GetJSON Security Issues. Copying URL and pasting in the browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, security

Im using the jQuery GetJSON call in my asp page. Its something like this..

```
 $.ajax({
    url: myUrl/myPage.aspx?callback=BookARoom,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

This will actually end up in a room being booked in my system.
But the issue is what if a user copies this URL and pastes it in the browser URL and runs it, the room would get booked.
Since he already has the session, i can't differentiate in the ASP Pages.
So how do i prevent this ???

Comment: *Why* would the user do that? If they're really set on messing things up, they could send a post request from the commandline - but I don't see why they'd do either. Seems like a non-issue to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Requests are not supposed to be dependent on "how" they are sent by the client. The request can be either from your javascript code, from browser address bar or from some other way.

In case you **really** just want to avoid the access from browser address bar, then you can make the aspx page to only work on POST requests as browser address bar can only send GET requests.

Comment: So all i need to do is make the aspx page accept POST reqeusts ! Thanks a Lot !

Comment: Also from jquery code make use of post() method

Comment: but does post method support retrieval of data ??

Comment: Yes.. ex: when u submit a form a post request is send to server and you receive a new page

Comment: thank you so much ! i can differentiate between browser address bar requests now ! BTW i did with Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"].ToLower() != "xmlhttprequest"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue why user can't do that. But if your idea to make sure this is accessed only through AJAX, you can check the `X-Requested-With` header to determine whether the request is made using AJAX Or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using a POST instead of a GET would stop it happening when they pasted a URL into the browser at least.